# how to display count on table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how to query count schedule_id <=8 on table staff_schedule

[image: ex : record table]

result like this :

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use group by and having if you need  limit the result for count <= 8

```
select schedule.schedule_id, count(*) 
from schedule
inner join staff_schedule on schedule.schedule_id = staff_schedule.schedule_id 
group by  schedule_id
having count(*) <= 8
```